# Dynamically choosing Email Template with workflow or flow

Tags: apex, workflow, email-template, visual-workflow

So I have an ask from a user to be able to create,save and edit email templates.  Editing, saving and creating is not an issue; it's the workflows tied to the templates that I'm having issues with. Right now the company has 15 email templates, on the object they have a picklist which displays and allows the user to choose which email template to send for this record.  There are also 15 different workflows that monitor this object with criteria that says. "If the email_template__c field = "Template1" then it sends template 1.  They have 15 workflows all like this so the second workflow says "If the email_template__c field = "Template2" send template 2. So if I allow the user to create a new template and save it, great but now there is not workflow associated with this new template so it will never send.  Now I could use the metadata API to dynamically create a workflow for it, but I don't like that idea.  For one it bypasses source control and the workflows would only exist on production and not sandboxes.

What I would love to do is create a workflow that dynamically chooses which template to send.  Like basically a workflow that says, if this email_Template__c field is not null use the field to pick and send a specific template.

Does anyone know if this can be done?  Or possibly a work around that uses flows or something else? I would really rather not write apex code to send the emails.

Thanks,

Comment: Are you opposed to using a Flow Plugin for this?

Comment: You should be able to use a decision element in a flow to choose the template.  Don't think you can do this w regular workflows, though depending on what is unique about each template, you may be able to use a single visualforce email template that can dynamically adjust the content based on your parameters.

Comment: ^ this. Can use a flow plugin to modify the content based off your pick list values.

Comment: Flows can use regular email alerts, same as workflow, but you can use a decision element to select the correct one.  As you already have the email alerts in place that seems like the easiest solution.

Comment: None of these work.  When designing the flow or process builder to send the email, it requires me to choose which template to use.  I need to choose which template to use at runtime.  What would be great is if I can set a workflow, process or flow to Say `If status__c = send mail' then send the template in field chosen_email_template__c`  Right now with 10 email templates I need 10 workflows that say if email_temp__c = custom1 then send custom1.